# Oracle BI Publisher: Error occurred on retrieving data xml

Tags: bi-publisher

While viewing a report in BI Publisher, the interactive viewer starts loading then displays the following error:
[image]

if I choose a different way to view (HTML, Excel) it works fine. I checked the permissions of my user and added all of them to the data source, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and it turned out to be a BI Publisher connection permissions issue.  The role of the person encountering the error was not added to the connection.